# How to fix my code's error "List index out of range"

Tags: python

How do I fix the error my code comes up with the following?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 143, in <module>
     print(question_list2[random_int])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code in question:

```
question_list2 = []

question_list2.append(" the marines are ___ based opreatives  ")
question_list2.append(" for under water travel marines use _____ ")
question_list2.append(" the avergae marine trains for _ weeks ")

answer_list2 = []

answer_list2.append("sea")
answer_list2.append("subamrines")
answer_list2.append("13")

top_index = 4
correct = 0

for i in range (0,4):

    random_int = random.randint(0,top_index)

    print(question_list2[random_int])

    top_index = top_index - 1

    user_answer1 = input("fill in the blank with the correct word ")

    if user_answer == answer_list1[random_int]:

        correct = correct + 3

    del question_list1[random_int]
    del answer_list1[random_int]
```

Comment: Try printing out `random_int` on the line before the error. It would seem you can get a value that is not a valid index for `question_list2`.

Comment: You are setting random int from 0-4 which is inclusive, meaning 4 is a possible output. Your list is only 3 long to begin with which is a problem in and of itself. As you del elements from the list, the list gets shorter, at which point, answer_list1[3] will also throw an error. Try to search for a basic tutorial online about python list and indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you only have three things on your list. The range should be range(0,3) and maybe your top_index should be top_index = 2.

Since the indexes on your list are [0,1,2]

The first item in list > index = 0

The second item in list > index = 1

The third item in list > index = 2

Answer (score 2):

From the [random docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.randint)

> random.randint(a, b)
>    Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b

This means that:

```
top_index = 4
random_int = random.randint(0,top_index)
```

Has the possibility of setting `random_int` to  `3` or `4` which are outside the range of your list which only has three items with index `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Rather than mutating your lists and using indexes, it might be easier to make a list of indexes, shuffle it, then iterate over it:

```
indexes = random.sample(range(0, len(question_list)), k = len(question_list))

for i in indexes:
    # etc...
```

If you kept the questions and answers together in a single list, you could do away with the indexes altogether. This would be a good use for [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
import random
from collections import namedtuple

qa = namedtuple('QA', ['question', 'answer'])

question_list = [
    qa(" the marines are ___ based opreatives  ", 'sea'),
    qa(" for under water travel marines use _____ ",'submarines'),
    qa(" the avergae marine trains for _ weeks ", '13')
]

random.shuffle(question_list)

correct = 0
for qa in question_list:
    print(qa.question)
    user_answer = input("fill in the blank with the correct word ")

    if user_answer == qa.answer:
        correct = correct + 1
```